# MariaDB How to ORDER BY results by multiple fields using weighting?

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have a `products` table on database toto, looking like this:

```sql
MariaDB [toto]> desc products;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| product_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sold_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rate       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Admitting now I have theses data:

```sql
MariaDB [toto]> select * from products;
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | sold_at             | rate     | name      |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        400 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 |     NULL | product_1 |
|  2 |        399 | NULL                |      728 | product_2 |
|  3 |        401 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 |   100000 | product_3 |
|  4 |        398 | NULL                | 99999999 | product_4 |
|  5 |        404 | 2023-04-14 07:45:00 |        1 | product_5 |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

My goal is to sort all those results by `rate` DESC, with all products having a `sold_at` value not null first, meanings I would like to have all my non null `sold_at` equal to 1 and null `sold_at` to 0.
to looks like something like:

```sql
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | product_id | sold_at             | rate     | name      |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
|  3 |        401 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 |   100000 | product_3 |
|  5 |        404 | 2023-04-14 07:45:00 |        1 | product_5 |
|  1 |        400 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 |     NULL | product_1 |
|  4 |        398 | NULL                | 99999999 | product_4 |
|  2 |        399 | NULL                |      728 | product_2 |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

> Note that some products may have a `sold_at` with a NULL rate.

### I currently tried multiple approach but none worked, such as:

```sql
WITH data AS (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rate DESC) SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY sold_at;
```

---

```sql
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rate DESC, sold_at ASC;
```

I know why that doesn't works (because `sold_at` is currently being ordered too using it's date, but I don't know how to do it).

Comment: Use a case expression in the ORDER BY to put NULL values last.

Comment: `sold_at equal to 1 and null sold_at to 0` -> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/is-null/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MariaDB, we could phrase this as:

```
select *
from mytable
order by (sold_at is null), rate desc
```

In the context of an `order by` clause, predicate `sold_at is null` evaluates as `1` if true, and `0` if false - so this puts non-null values first.

| id | product_id | sold_at | rate | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 401 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 | 100000 | product_3 |
| 5 | 404 | 2023-04-14 07:45:00 | 1 | product_5 |
| 1 | 400 | 2023-04-14 07:28:44 | *null* | product_1 |
| 4 | 398 | *null* | 99999999 | product_4 |
| 2 | 399 | *null* | 728 | product_2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/brA1SiQN)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 order by case when sold_at is null then 1 else 0 end, rate desc
```